# What is the remainder when 10,987,654 is divided by 2,103?

Tags: divisibility

What is a simple way to solve this problem? I solve this problem by actually dividing $10,987,654$ by $2,103$, which should not be a simple way.

> What is the remainder when $10,987,654$ is divided by $2,103$?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $2013$? That would make the problem much nicer and I'd expect this to be from some recent contest.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I checked again. It is 2103, not 2013. I am not sure whether the book misprinted the number. Let's assume it is 2013, then how to solve the problem?

Comment: dividing seems pretty easy

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just do long division?

Comment: Can you not tag every single problem with only chinese-remainder-theorem?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo This is a math competition problem. So I don't think it means using dividing method.

Comment: @learning Darn it. In that case, division is probably the best way, since taking it $\mod 701$ is not that much easier than $\mod 2103$, and $701$ is prime. Do you know what competition it's from?

Answer (score 1):

$\pmod {2103} :$

$\color{red}{10 987} 654 \equiv \color{red}{472}654$

$\color{red}{4726}54\equiv \color{red}{520}54$

$\color{red}{5205}4\equiv \color{red}{999}4$

$\color{red}{9994}\equiv \color{red}{1582}$

So yeah it's boring but not too hard without a calculator.

Comment: Took me the best part of 18 seconds. I even got the quotient, so $+1$ just for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

As is tagged in your question, you can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem. We have that

$$2013=3\cdot11\cdot61$$

So we wish to find $$a\mod k$$ for $a=10987654$ and each of $k\in\{3,11,61\}$. These are fairly easy to calculate, and we get the equivalences

$$a\equiv1\mod 3$$

$$a\equiv7\mod 11$$

$$a\equiv29\mod 61$$

We now note that the number $29$ solves each of the second and third congruences, so we just want to add multiples of $671=11\cdot61$ to it to get it to be $\equiv1\mod3$. We have $$29+671=700\equiv1\mod3$$

so we get that

$$10987654\equiv 700\mod 2013$$

Comment: he wrote 2103, although I do think he meant 2013

Comment: @suomynonA Read the comments on the question. Edit: Never mind.